# How to speed up IMDb ratings plugin in WP?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I tried to implement [IMDb ratings plugin](http://www.imdb.com/plugins) in WP, in this way:
I made a **meta box** and I copy in it the HTML code generated by the **IMDb ratings plugin** from IMDb site, **[here is the code generated by plugin](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=oVLDh)**, but when loading the website, plugin content is very slow (a few seconds).

Meta box:

```
        array(
        'label' => 'iMDb Rating',
        'desc'  => 'iMDb Rating Script',
        'id' => 'imdb-rating',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'std' => ''
        ),
```

Display meta box method in post:

```
<?php $test_field_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'imdb-rating', true ); echo $test_field_value; ?>
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to make the plugin to load faster, or to implement it in a good way to avoid the slow display?

I asked on [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85725/how-to-implement-imdb-ratings-plugin-in-wp-in-a-good-way) too, but i was redirected here.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can suggest:

- Load the IMDB data using AJAX, that way page will render first and then you can load the rest of the data. You could even create a custom wordpress page in your theme that loads the plugin and call this from your on page js.
- Cache the data so that you only reload on a regular basis. Ive not used the plugin so my guess is you would probably need to do a little rewriting to get that happening.

Comment: I think there must be an easier way.

Comment: Maybe there is; the ajax way shouldnt be too hard though; caching on the other hand would be much more complex.